# ClassCastException blues

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, casting, classcastexception

I've had it up to about my nose hairs with java generic types. I'm trying to create a generic 2D array that I can mess around with (this is 90% experimenting, 10% useful to class and such). I'm just a bit confused by the error I'm getting. I understand the words it's yelling at me, but I don't understand them or how to fix it. Here's the code:

```
private T[][] grid;
private int size;
private int hw;
private int r_curr = 0;
private int c_curr = 0;
private Class<T> currclass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Array2D(Class<T> type, int r){
    currclass = type;
    hw = r;
    size = r*r;
    int count = 0;

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    grid = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(type, r);
    //TODO: This is the bit where I get the following error
    //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    //[Ljava.lang.Boolean; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        grid[i] = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, r);
        for(int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++){
            grid[i][j] = null;
            count ++;
        }
    }
    if(!(size == count)){
        if(verbose){System.out.println("ALERT...Failed to successfully create array!");}
        grid = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(type, r);
    }
}
```

Now don't tell me about other broke stuff you find in there (I'm sure it exists, haha), I'm still writing it, but the generics/ casting bit has me stumped.

EDIT: here's the stack trace. There's not really too much here.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Boolean; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;
at mat.Array2D.<init>(Array2D.java:22)
at mat.BinMatrix.generateMatrix(BinMatrix.java:24)
at mat.BinMatrix.<init>(BinMatrix.java:9)
at mat.Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace of your exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
  grid = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(currclass, r, r);
```

... to get what you want for the 2D array.

---

To explain the space magic, there are two `Array.newInstance` methods.  One takes a single size value, and returns a single dimension array — [`Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29).  The other takes a variable number of size values and returns a multiple dimension array — [`Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29).  The second one is the version that I've proposed you use.

There is some additional information available on the relationship between varargs and arrays in the Java 1.5.0 documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).  In particular, this:

```
  grid = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(currclass, r, r);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
  grid = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(currclass, new int[] { r, r });
```

And the latter should compile (and function) equally well.

Comment: What's that second integer for? I thought newInstance() took an integer or an array of integers?

Comment: Weird, I think that may have actually worked. Please explain your space magic to me.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.newInstance(type, r)` : Creates a new array with the specified **component type** and length.

It seems you are passing the `type` as `boolean` to `newInstance` method, and then trying to convert this boolean array to Object array using the cast in this statement:

```
grid = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(type, r);
```

which is causing ClassCastException

Comment: So I guess the real question I'm asking is how I can initialize grid as a two dimensional array of my mystery object? If I take the cast away, Eclipse starts yelling at me more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form of `Array.newInstance()` that takes multiple dimensions. But note that that method is nothing magical. It is just a convenience method for single-dimensional array creation that also initializes subarrays.

Just like how normal multi-dimensional array creation:

```
Boolean[][] foo = new Boolean[r][r];
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```
Boolean[][] foo = new Boolean[r][];
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    foo[i] = new Boolean[r];
```

The multi-dimensional `Array.newInstance()`:

```
grid = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(currclass, r, r);
```

can also be written in terms of the single-dimensional `Array.newInstance()`:

```
Class currArrayClass = Array.newInstance(currclass, 0).getClass();
grid = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(currArrayClass, r);
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    grid[i] = (T[]) Array.newInstance(currclass, r);
```